# Map string 1 and 0 to true or false

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map some data, from a string to a boolean (if possible).

Say I have this array (all the values are of type string).

```
var values = array["1", "0", "0", "1", "SomethingElse"];
```

I want to map the 1s to true, 0s to value, and SomethingElse just returns itself.

My idea is to have a map object

```
map = {
    1: true,
    0: false  
};
```

Then have a wrapper function check if the key is set, if not return itself. Something like this

```
function mapValue(val) {
    return (isset(map[val])) ? map[val] : val;
}

var newValues = [];
angular.forEach(values, function(val, key) {
    newValues[key] = mapValue(val);
});
```

That's my rough plan. Is this a good approach  to this problem? Or is there a much simpler way I could do this?

Comment: Seems like a good approach to me. (I assume `isset` is pseudo-code for `hasOwnProperty`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, like this

```
var values = ["1", "0", "0", "1", "SomethingElse"],
    map    = { 1: true, 0: false };

console.log(values.map(function(currentItem) {
    return map.hasOwnProperty(currentItem) ? map[currentItem] : currentItem;
}));
# [ true, false, false, true, 'SomethingElse' ]
```